# Why the ultra product of finite sets is not necessarily finite?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Why the ultara product of finite sets can be infinite?
I know the ultra product of real numbers  is not a complete field but in this case it is because completeness is not definable in first order logic.
But in the case of finite sets i don't under stand why?
How can i prove finitness is not definable in first order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the case of taking the ultraproduct of finite sets of increasing size - for example, $\prod_n\{1,\ldots,n\}/U$ for some nonprincipal ultrafilter $U$ of $\omega$. For each $n$, the formula "there are more than $n$ elements" is true of all but finitely many of the component sets, so it's true of the ultraproduct. So the ultraproduct has size $>n$ for every $n$, and is therefore infinite.

We can now conclude from this that finiteness isn't a first-order property - if it were, it should have been preserved by the ultraproduct. It's also possible to prove that finiteness isn't first-order using Compactness (that's the more typical way, as far as I know) but this is more direct in this case.

Comment: It's worth noting that one proof of compactness is by constructing the ultraproduct.